# Displaying HTML only if block is rendered

Tags: python, wsgi, mako

I am currently developing a web page in Python and am using Mako as a template engine. Previously I have used PHP with the Joomla framework. From there, a common template technique was to check if a module position has modules to display and in that case load some wrapping code (for example a wrapping `div`) and then insert the module in between.

For mako the comparison for the module would be a `<%block />` that will then get inserted by the inherting file. However, I cannot figure out a neat way to display the wrapping code.

Example from Joomla:

```
<div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="my_position" style="none" />
</div>
```

The `jdoc` line is equivalent to `<%block name="my_position" />` as in both cases the content gets replaced depending on the actual page. Now my question is: How to elegantly display the wrapping `div` when it should *not* be rendered when there is no `block` content? Does Mako provide an elegant solution for this that I am just overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have found some sort of solution, but it is not pretty so I would prefer if someone could come up with a cleaner solution:

```
<%namespace name="layout" file="layout.mako" />
<%block name="my_position">
    <%def name="my_element()">
        ## Actual position content here
    </%def>
    ${layout.render_my_position(my_element)}
</%block>
```

Then, in `layout.mako`:

```
<%block name="banner" />
...
<%def name="render_my_position(my_element)">
    <div>
        ${my_element()}
    </div>
</%def>
```

This solution works and the amount to copy paste is relatively small while a change of the wrapping div is easy. However, this is still far from an optimal solution so maybe someone has a better idea

Comment: why do you need the wrapping div? why not include it mako temlate- so it would be rendered only if the block was called

Comment: Because I potentially have different content for the block but always the same wrapping element.